# MongoDB: How to ignore error while importing JSON file?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to import a JSON file into mongo db using `mongoimport`. The import statement stops when it finds an invalid JSON in the file. I would like to ignore the error and keep importing the other valid JSON documents. How to do that using `mongoimport` ?

Edit 1: Below is the error I'm getting

```
2016-06-28T19:43:37.343+0530    Failed: error processing document #514397: 
invalid character '\f' in string literal
```

Comment: are you using the option  --stopOnError ? Otherwise it should not stop

Comment: No I'm not using that option.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the -parseGrace option with one of these parameters

- autoCast
- skipField
- skipRow
- stop (default)

Comment: parseGrace has no effect when importing JSON documents.